# Save a page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a jsp page which contains a table with id 'department'. There is a button named 'Save'. When I click Save button then it should give an option to save the department table as text file or pdf. For this I write a javascript function. But its not working. Can anybody help me? My javascript function is given below--

```
function Save() {
    var saveContent = document.getElementById("department");
    document.execCommand("SaveAs",true, saveContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should accede to content

```
var content = saveContent. innerHTML
```

Now can you work with this content. send with Ajax or execute a command.